# Troubles with gnuplottex and TeXShop

Tags: texshop, gnuplot, gnuplottex

I've had some trouble using the `epslatex` terminal in gnuplot, then I discovered that was also possible to plot directly from LaTeX using the `\usepackage{gnuplottex}`. Anyway I've found some problems in compiling the LaTeX code directly from my TeX editor (which is TeXShop for Mac). 
In fact, if i compile the code

```
%foo.tex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{gnuplottex}


\begin{document}

/* TeX stuff */

 \begin{figure}%
    \centering%
    \begin{gnuplot}[terminal=epslatex, terminaloptions=color]
        set key box top left
        set key width 4
        set xr [-5:5]
        set yr [-1:1]
        set xlabel '$x$'
        set ylabel '$y$'
        plot sin(x) w l lc 1 t '$\sin(x)$',\
        cos(x) w l lc 2 dt 2 t '$\cos(x)$',\
        tan(x) w l lc 3 t '$\tan(x)$',\
        tanh(x) w l lc 4 t '$\tanh(x)$'
    \end{gnuplot}
    \caption{!!!Sample!!!}%
    \label{pic:epslatex}%
 \end{figure}%
\end{document}
```

I can't get the desired output and the plot. Even if it's running and typesetting without errors the output is the right TeX document without the desired plot (instead of which i get a blank figure with the caption). 
[image: the figure]
I've found a solution by running from the *terminal* the command

```
pdflatex --shell-escape foo.tex
```

which I don't really understand the meaning. Now I get the correct output, but I prefer to typeset from TeXShop, in order not to compile in 2 different ways the same document. Any suggestions?[image: the right plot]
If the problem is with TexShop, does anybody know a place where I can find a detailed guide on how to plot with gnuplot's `epslatex` terminal? Because I don't even understand how to make a pdf out of my `.tex` and `.eps` output, and it's very frustrating not to be able to include the result in LaTeX after the whole work!
Thank you all!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28039856/how-do-i-add-the-shell-escape-option-in-texshop

Comment: Great! Very useful! ThY so much!